# v-webmail using open source to try to fix a few

Tags: php, sendmail

I called v-webmail using open source to try to fix a few

However, at the time of installation,

Unfortunately this application needs the imap extension 
loaded and the version of php to be at least 4.1.0 to run.
Other configuration parameters may also be faulty.

Config file local.config.xml: Writeable!
IMAP Extension loaded: Loaded Message is output.

This file is normally created local.config.xml, and gave the necessary permission to 644.

I wonder what caused this error to why.

Why this error occurred ever know about them?

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?  And what version of English?!

Comment: php version is 4.4.9AnNyung

Comment: did you install and configure the server yourself?  it sounds like php needs to be recompiled with the proper imap extension